# xarray slow to save netCDF

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I find xarray to be very slow to save a dataset to netCDF. I suspect the reason for this is that the .to_netcdf() command first has to load the data before saving it. For an example I get the following timings:

Example a)

```
ds.to_netcdf(file_path) # ~6 minutes
```

Example b)

```
ds.load() # ~6 minutes
ds.to_netcdf(file_path) # <1 second
```

It would seem the slow down comes from loading. Is there any way circumventing this load or speeding this process up?

An explicit example of (a) that I am working with is as follows:

```
import xarray            as xr
import numpy             as np
from Python import config, read
from Python import array_opperations as ao

class Model(read.Read):

    def __init__(self, case, mean=1):
        self.readPath = config.readPath(case)
        self.load_dataset(['Vorticity.nc', 'ssh.nc', 'vels_snap.nc', 'hFac.nc'],
                          ['DXC', 'DYC', 'DXG', 'DYG',]) #load a dataset using the xarray open_dataset functionality
        self.ds = self.ds.sel(TIME=slice('1980-01-08', '1981-01-07'))
        self.KE(mean=mean)


    def KE(self, mean=1):
        '''
        Calculates the kinetic energy term of the momentum budget according
        to KEscheme=0
        '''
        u = self.ds['UVEL']
        v = self.ds['VVEL']

        def calc(u, v):
            u2 = u**2
            v2 = v**2

            KE = 0.25 * ( u2 + ao.roll(u2, 'LONGITUDE', -1) +
                          v2 + ao.roll(v2, 'LATITUDE',  -1) )

            KEx = - ao.padded_diff(KE, 'LONGITUDE') / self.ds['DXC']
            KEy = - ao.padded_diff(KE, 'LATITUDE')  / self.ds['DYC']
            return KEx, KEy

        if mean:
            u_mean = u.mean(dim='TIME', skipna=True)
            v_mean = v.mean(dim='TIME', skipna=True)

            u_rey = u - u_mean
            v_rey = v - v_mean

            KEx, KEy = calc(u_mean, v_mean)
            KExRey, KEyRey = calc(u_rey, v_rey)

            KE_terms = [KEx.rename('u_gradKE'), KEy.rename('v_gradKE'),
                  KExRey.rename('u_gradKERey'), KEyRey.rename('v_gradKERey')]
        else:
            KEx, KEy = calc(u, v)
            KE_terms = [KEx.rename('u_gradKE'), KEy.rename('v_gradKE')]

        KE_nc = xr.merge(KE_terms)
        KE_nc.to_netcdf(self.readPath + 'offlineKE.nc', unlimited_dims='TIME')
```

The KE function runs real fast due to the xarray functionality but as soon as it gets to the last (.to_netcdf) line it really lags.

Here is my dataset loading method:

```
def load_dataset(self, nc_files, data_files):
    '''
    Load all NetCDF files listed
    '''
    file_paths = [self.readPath + file for file in nc_files]
    self.ds = xr.open_mfdataset(file_paths, chunks={'LATITUDE':200, 'LONGITUDE':200})
    LAT = self.ds.coords['LATITUDE'].values
    LON = self.ds.coords['LONGITUDE'].values

    for file in data_files:
        _, x, y, z, _, prec = self.readMeta(self.readPath + file + '.meta')
        data = self.readBin(file + '.data', x=x, y=y, z=z, dtype=prec)
        self.ds = xr.merge([ self.ds,
                             xr.DataArray(data,
                  coords=[LAT,LON], dims=['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']
                          ).to_dataset(name=file)] )

    self.ds = xr.merge([ self.ds,
                         xr.DataArray(np.ones(self.ds['DXC'].shape)*5000.0,
               coords=[LAT,LON], dims=['LATITUDE','LONGITUDE']
                       ).to_dataset(name='DRF')] )
```

Comment: Can you share something about how you created the dataset? Sometimes loading is unavoidably slow, but it can often be optimized.

Comment: @shoyer I have added a snippet of the relevant code for this problem, the actual loading of the netCDF data is done from a separate class (named Read). Would it help to see this too? I didn't want to overload the page with code if it is irrelevant.

Comment: @rpat - are you using `open_mfdataset` in `Read` or are you using dask?

Comment: Does it speed things up to load the data before doing any computation on it? Note this tip from the xarray docs: xarray’s lazy loading of remote or on-disk datasets is often but not always desirable. Before performing computationally intense operations, it is often a good idea to load a Dataset (or DataArray) entirely into memory by invoking the load() method.

Comment: @jhamman I have used `open_mfdataset`, I have now added this code snipet to the post. @shoyer I tried putting .load() in before doing computation but it turns out my dataset is too large for the memory I am working with so I get a memory error.

Comment: @rpat - I'm guessing you are using the default/threaded dask scheduler. In some cases using the multiprocessing or distributed schedulers can help speed up chunked reads. You may also try increasing your chunksize.