# Generating a NetCDF from a text file

Tags: pandas, netcdf

Using Python can I open a text file, read it into an array, then save the file as a NetCDF?

The following script I wrote was not successful.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as im

path = 'C:\path\to\data'
grb = [[]]
for fn in os.listdir(path):
    file = os.path.join(path,fn)
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        df = pd.read_table(file,skiprows=6)
        grb.append(df)

        df2 = pd.np.array(grb)

        #imarray = im.fromarray(df2) ##cannot handle this data type

        #imarray.save('Save_Array_as_TIFF.tif')
```

Comment: Why wasn't it successful?

Comment: Have you thought about using ncgen for this?  http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/netcdf/ncgen.html

Answer (score -2):

i once used xray or xarray (they renamed them selfs) to get a NetCDF file into an ascii dataframe... i just googled and appearantly they have a to_netcdf function

import xarray and it allows you to treat dataframes just like pandas.
so give this a try:

```
df.to_netcdf(file_path)
```

[xarray slow to save netCDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47238155/xarray-slow-to-save-netcdf)